# id_token undefined google api nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-api, jwt

I am having an issue with my google APi using a JWT token, I have been having trouble impersonating users for checking calendar avaliability, and I started back tracing and found when I output the JWT token after an authorize, I get the following:

```
    { access_token: '****',
  token_type: 'Bearer',
  expiry_date: 1589294984000,
  id_token: undefined,
  refresh_token: 'jwt-placeholder' }
```

the id_token comes back undefined. I have set up everything in my cloud services and I call the authorization with a config file

```
var googleAuthorization = require('../config/calendarConfig.js').jwtClient;
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const calendar = google.calendar('v3');
    googleAuthorization.authorize(function(err, token) {
        if(err) {
            reject(console.log({status: 1, message: 'Google Authorization Failed: ' + err}));
        } else {
            console.log(token);
        }
    });
```

and the config file:

```
var google = require('googleapis');
var googleAauth = require('google-auth-library');
var scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user'];
var key = require('./intranet-google-service-account.json');
var jwtClient = new google.google.auth.JWT(key.client_email, null, key.private_key, scopes, 
       "service@accountemail.com");
exports.jwtClient = jwtClient;
```

Can anyone see what I might be doing wrong to not get an ID token back?

Comment: did you get any solution?